# Pass the data between PHP and Python Script

Tags: php, python, apache, web-scraping, python-requests

I have created a Python script that scrapes the data on the website after logging in based on the Start Date and End Date and stored in JSON. It works fine since I am passing dates static in script  But I want to pass those two dates from PHP as parameters to Python script and pass those JSON data to the client side(in PHP) as Response. I have used requests and BeautifulSoap for this. I am stuck in Dynamic part? Can you guide me on how to do this?

Comment: while running the python script, you can pass runtime arguments right? pass the star time and end time as arguments to the python call, the response can be received via exec(" python script.py startime endtime") ?? no?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website where you get specific answers to specific questions related to programming. Guiding you through your project is not a service we offer here.

Comment: Thanks, @DanyalSandeelo for guiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can do something like:

```
<?php
    $start_date = "2019-04-26";
    $end_date = "2019-04-30";
    $command = "/path/to/script/script.py -s $start_date -e $end_date";
    exec($command);
?>
```

AND Python Script:

```
import sys
count = 0
for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg == "-s":
        START = sys.argv[count+1]
    elif arg == "-e":
        END = sys.argv[count+1]
    count+=1
# Here you will get your START & END date.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.fine on the local machine. I got what I want But How to execute if Python file is on different Server?

Comment: You can use absolute path of script.